# Unable to find PyForms 'loggingbootstrap' dependency

Tags: python-3.x, pyforms

I'm trying to run a basic pyforms program with Python 3, but get the following error:

```
    import pyforms
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyforms\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import loggingbootstrap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'loggingbootstrap'
```

I'm sure I must be missing something obvious here as there is no trace of this module on Google.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too. There seems to be an undocumented dependency on this module: https://bitbucket.org/fchampalimaud/logging-bootstrap

You can install it with `pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/fchampalimaud/logging-bootstrap.git`.

(As a side note, Pyforms is currently rather difficult to install, because of its poor documentation and somewhat esoteric dependencies. This is only one of several problems I faced. I was thinking about using it in a project, but decided now to look for something else because other people need to be able to install my product smoothly.)

Answer (score 1):

When installing PyForms for Python 3, PyForms itself and 2 dependencies should NOT be installed straight from pypi. Instead you want to use :

```
pip install git+https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pyforms.git --upgrade
pip install git+https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pysettings.git --upgrade
pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/fchampalimaud/logging-bootstrap.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact error as well. I just commented out the import in **init** and it does not seem to have broken anything yet. This is probably a terrible solution, but it worked.